# Flat line in Plot PDF of empirical data

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions, discrete

I am currently trying to plot the probability density function [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) of an empirical data set. However, unfortunately, I always receive just a flat line in the [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

My code is as follows:

```
empdist = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
Plot[PDF[empdist , x], {x, 0, Max[data]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I use the [`DiscretePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html) function it works, however then there are lines to the points on the x-axis which I do not want as am fitting another distribution on top of it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can try `EstimatedDistribution` or `FindDistribution` if you want to try to get a continuous distribution for your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For `EmpiricalDistribution`, don't use `Plot` but `DiscretePlot`

A [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) of [`EmpiricalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) of a finite set of data is necessarily a series of [`DiracDelta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html) at each data point. [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) has problem with the discontinuity of that function. If you  look at the documentation of [`EmpiricalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) you will see it uses [`DiscretePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html).  Plotting that and seen an horizontal set of points may not look very meaningful to you but is correct. If you don't want [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) (the vertical lines)  just set it to `None`.

```
ed = EmpiricalDistribution[data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 25]];
DiscretePlot[PDF[ed, x], {x, data}, Filling -> None]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### `SmoothKernelDistribution`

If you need a "Kernel" other than a [`DiracDelta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html) so that points "add to another", then you should use [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html)

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], x]
 , {x, -2, 2}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This is related to [`HistogramDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramDistribution.html), but continuous, and to [`SmoothHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html).
But beware that this is a parametric estimation, you need to chose a parameter in this case a bandwidth (even if the default is Automatic), and the distribution you get will depend on that choice. A good value could be the intrinsic uncertainty of your measurement.

### `EstimatedDistribution`

On the other hand if you already know what the distribution is, but just need to define empirically the coefficients, then use [`EstimatedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html) (as suggested by N.J.Evans)

```
ed = EstimatedDistribution[data, NormalDistribution[m, s]]
(* NormalDistribution[0.161522, 0.740823] *)

Plot[Evaluate@PDF[ed, x], {x, -2, 2}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @rhermans for your extensive explanations! It was very helpful!

Comment: @AlexanderHempfing, I'm happy to help, and glad you appreciate it. **There is a way to return the favour**, not to me, but to the community. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes. Did something cool or pedagogical?  Share what you have learned! You have posted 8 questions, time to offer an answer!

Comment: You are right! Thank you for the suggestion. I am currently working on my thesis and will share some code - at least the interesting stuff - as soon as I am finished. And I will try to engage more in the community - at least if I am able to offer a solution to problems posted here.  :)